# Is there any evidence that the daff was also played in environments filled with drinking and lewdness?

Tags: history, alcohol, music

I was reading an article that said that mentioned that the daff too was instrument that was associated with drinking and lewdness. Can anyone confirm this with any evidence?

This is what is written in the article (urdu):

> شراب اور جوئے کی انھی مجالس میں کیف و سرور کو بڑھانے کے لیے مغنیات اور ان کے ساتھ دف، طبل اور دیگر آلات موسیقی بھی فراہم رہتے تھے

Rough Translation:

> In gatherings including liquor and gambling, songstresses, the daff, the tabla and other musical instruments would be present as a means of entertainment.

Link of the article:

> http://www.al-mawrid.org/index.php/articles_urdu/view/Mosiqi-Ki-Hurmat-2

Comment: Does this article say it was associated with them during al-Jahilayh or even afterwards?

Comment: @Medi1Saif The article doesn't really specify whether this association was before or after al-Jahiliyah. My guess is that maybe some people - at least those that didn't convert - still used the daff in these settings.

Comment: @Medi1Saif Do you know of any evidence?

Comment: No, but it would be helpful if you could share the article.

Comment: @Medi1Saif I added what was written in the article. It was in Urdu so I was only able to roughly translate what was written.